# Kivy service stops when app is closed

Tags: android, python, android-service, kivy

I'm starting a service from my Kivy app:

```
service = autoclass('net.saband.myapp.ServiceMyservice')
mActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
service.start(mActivity, '')
```

It works. And if I close my app using the back button my service still works. But if I close my app by swiping it out from the recent apps list the service dies.

I've found [this issue](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/267) and tried to use `startForeground` guided by [this article](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Background-Service-using-P4A-android.service). It works but the notification is not removable so this solution doesn't suit me.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651009/android-service-stops-when-app-is-closed) and it looks like I could be helped using START_STICKY... but it's kivy service so how can I implement it? I've tried to edit Service.tmpl.java in my python-for-android templates and change this:

```
public class Service{{ name|capitalize }} extends PythonService {
    {% if sticky %}
    @Override
    public int startType() {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    {% endif %}
...
```

to this:

```
public class Service{{ name|capitalize }} extends PythonService {

    @Override
    public int startType() {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

(Yes, I understand that `{% if sticky %}` means that I can set it somewhere but in the [official docs](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/) there is not a word about it.)

But nothing changed, the service still dies. According the logs the restart is scheduled:

```
11-17 22:52:07.140  1496  1511 I ActivityManager: Killing 29431:net.saband.myapp/u0a122 (adj 9): remove task
11-17 22:52:07.219  1496  3404 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{3c605b3 u0 net.saband.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
11-17 22:52:07.220  1496  3404 W WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{5ed4ff u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{3c605b3 u0 net.saband.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
11-17 22:52:07.225  1496  2871 W WindowManager: Failed looking up window
11-17 22:52:07.225  1496  2871 W WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@c7f2770 does not exist
11-17 22:52:07.225  1496  2871 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8821)
11-17 22:52:07.225  1496  2871 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8812)
11-17 22:52:07.225  1496  2871 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1212)
11-17 22:52:07.225  1496  2871 W WindowManager:     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:558)
11-17 22:52:07.225  1496  2871 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: null
11-17 22:52:07.247  1496  3311 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 29431
11-17 22:52:07.250  1496  3538 I ActivityManager: Killing 29366:net.saband.myapp:service_myservice/u0a122 (adj 8): remove task
11-17 22:52:07.304  1496  3557 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 29366
11-17 22:52:07.305  1496  3557 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service net.saband.myapp/.ServiceMyservice in 1000ms
```

But nothing happens.

I need the service to continue to work even when the app is closed by swiping it out from the recent apps list. And I need removable notifications. That's all. Many apps can do it. But is there a way to do it with Kivy and python-for-android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it. But this required changing the java code and the solution is hardcoded. It's strange and unpleasantly that python-for-android developers didn't foresee this.

Well, the solution.

Open file `.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/src/org/kivy/android/PythonService.java`. In function `startType()` change `START_NOT_STICKY` to `START_STICKY`:

```
public int startType() {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Now the service will be restarted. But this is not enough because after restart in function `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` intent will be null so we will get an error:

```
E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
```

So we need to add the if statement in this function:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (pythonThread != null) {
        Log.v("python service", "service exists, do not start again");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    if (intent != null) { 
        startIntent = intent;
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        androidPrivate = extras.getString("androidPrivate");
        androidArgument = extras.getString("androidArgument");
        serviceEntrypoint = extras.getString("serviceEntrypoint");
        pythonName = extras.getString("pythonName");
        pythonHome = extras.getString("pythonHome");
        pythonPath = extras.getString("pythonPath");
        pythonServiceArgument = extras.getString("pythonServiceArgument");

        pythonThread = new Thread(this);
        pythonThread.start();

        if (canDisplayNotification()) {
            doStartForeground(extras);
        }
    } else {
        pythonThread = new Thread(this);
        pythonThread.start();
    }

    return startType();
}
```

But this is steel not enough because now we have another error in `nativeStart` function call because there are no extras:

```
F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring'
```

So I've added the null check and some default values (2 of them is hardcoded) to `run()` function:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    String package_root = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    String app_root =  package_root + "/app";
    File app_root_file = new File(app_root);
    PythonUtil.loadLibraries(app_root_file);
    this.mService = this;

    if (androidPrivate == null) {
        androidPrivate = package_root;
    }
    if (androidArgument == null) {
        androidArgument = app_root;
    }
    if (serviceEntrypoint == null) {
        serviceEntrypoint = "./service/main.py"; // hardcoded
    }
    if (pythonName == null) {
        pythonName = "myservice"; // hardcoded
    }
    if (pythonHome == null) {
        pythonHome = app_root;
    }
    if (pythonPath == null) {
        pythonPath = package_root;
    }
    if (pythonServiceArgument == null) {
        pythonServiceArgument = app_root+":"+app_root+"/lib";
    }

    nativeStart(
        androidPrivate, androidArgument,
        serviceEntrypoint, pythonName,
        pythonHome, pythonPath,
        pythonServiceArgument);
    stopSelf();
}
```

Now it works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, yes it's easy to overlook things in this complex ecosystem.
Using `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` could have been a simpler option.
FYI there's an on-going PR to address that https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/2401