# Kivy - Android background service doesn't play audio

Tags: android, python, kivy, android-mediaplayer, background-service

I'm trying to play an audio file from the background service but it doesn't play it. The log says it does for a while and stop but the audio can't be heard.

The service is called when the app is paused:

```
from jnius import autoclass
service = autoclass('{}.Service{}'.format('kivyapp.music', 'S1'))
mActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
argument = ''
service.start(mActivity, argument)
```

/service/main.py

```
from jnius import autoclass
MediaPlayer = autoclass('android.media.MediaPlayer')
AudioManager = autoclass('android.media.AudioManager')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nowPlaying = MediaPlayer()
    nowPlaying.setDataSource('music00.mp3')
    nowPlaying.prepare()
    nowPlaying.setLooping(False)
    nowPlaying.setVolume(0.5, 0.5)
    nowPlaying.start()
```

I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong. Thank you. 
[Log.txt](https://15530009509605697547.googlegroups.com/attach/97fa007189288/log.txt?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHXJ4xEWwtwH2mptEBVfzSbiE1LcVbbYIyRFuRhF5H6a4FzjxZ63FHgkag7EA28FIKBcGMsy8keec7BBcZ2faBkfz0tEOdVTtq--Nbu8YZ-3W_2U9k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem was that, MediaPlayer didn't like me requesting for getCurrentPosition() every second. Also adding `:sticky` to my buildozer services = service:service.py seems to solve the problem.

Following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362161/kivy-service-stops-when-app-is-closed) steps also helped.